# ¿Cómo validar campos null en el where de una consulta linq?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, visual-studio-2019, linq-to-sql

Tengo una consulta de linq con un where. El problema es que en la base de datos hay registros que tienen *null* en la columna por la cual intento filtrar en el where. Y me arroja un error de objeto no establecido como instancia...

¿Cómo puedo hacer para consultar si es null?

Intente esto y me funciona, *pero me trae resultados que deseo mas los que tengan null en esa columna*.

```
.Where(
w => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(search)) ||
(w.Observaciones == null || w.Observaciones.ToLower().Contains(search))
```

Necesito filtrar por la columna Observaciones, pero que filtre por el search.

¿Que puedo hacer?

Saludos.

Comment: aca estas trayendo los null: w.Observaciones == null... si sacas eso?

Comment: El problema que se presentaba al sacar eso. Era que al venir null el campo Observaciones, me tiraba el error de elemento no establecido como instancia de un objeto. Ahora lo pude solucionar, con algo medio similar a lo que me habia propuesto Facundo mas abajo. Yo lo solucione asi "(w.Observaciones != null? w.Observaciones.ToLower().Contains(search):false)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fijate que en tu where, traés todos los elementos de la lista si `search` es `null`, o te quedás con los elementos tal que su columna `observaciones` sea `null` o contenga `search`. O sea que los elementos cuya columna `observaciones` sea `null` van a aparecer en la lista final, lo que justamente no querés.

Simplemente le tenés que decir que querés todos los elementos tal que `observaciones` no sea `null` y además contenga `search`. De esta manera, los elementos con `null` en `observaciones` no van a quedarse en la lista final a menos que `search` sea `null` y al mismo tiempo se evita cualquier problema al llamar a `ToLower` desde un campo `null`.

```
.Where(
w => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(search)) ||
(w.Observaciones != null && w.Observaciones.ToLower().Contains(search))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Facundo. Yo lo pude resolver de esta forma "(w.Observaciones != null? w.Observaciones.ToLower().Contains(search):false)" Pero la tuya parece mas prolija. Saludos

Comment: @CarlosJR exacto, es lo mismo a nivel resultado. No tengo idea si hay alguno más óptimo que otro, pero ambos parecen igual de mantenibles y tu respuesta parece más expresiva.